# Chrome - Fetch API cannot load file. How to workaround?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fetch-api, file-uri

I have the following two files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Web Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: #ddedff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    get_data('info.txt');
});
function get_data(file) {
    var request = new Request(file);
    fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        return response.text().then(function(text) {
            $('.text').html(text);
        });
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

**info.txt**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

When I open on `Mozilla Firefox` the file: `README.html` through this local `URI`:

```
file:///C:/testing/README.html
```

it works as expected, I mean, the text on file: `info.txt` is displayed properly.

But when I open the same `URI` on `Google Chrome` I get a blank screen and the following error on the console:

```
README.html:26 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/testing/README.md. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
get_data @ README.html:26
README.html:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at get_data (README.html:26)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (README.html:21)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Do you have what can I do so I can open local files on `Google Chrome` as I can do on `Mozilla Firefox`?

If I have to do some tweak on:

```
chrome://flags/
```

that's acceptable for me.

**EDIT**

I tried launching `Google Chrome` from the command line with the flag: `--allow-file-access-from-files` as recommended [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html) but now I get the following error:

```
README.html:26 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/testing/README.md. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
get_data @ README.html:26
README.html:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at get_data (README.html:26)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (README.html:21)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your problem is in the error message that Chrome provided. Chrome doesn't let you load local files through `file:///...` for security reasons.
If this is an application that you're working on to only be used locally, then you could download a Chrome application that creates a web server for you in a certain local directory. Web Server for Chrome is one that Google suggests when working on their Code Labs

Comment: there is no `chrome://flags/` tweak, only a command line tweak. Start chrome with command line option that allows `file:///` pages to access `file:///` resources like that - I don't know the option off hand, a quick google search should help

Comment: Seems like Chrome's `fetch` just won't play with `file://` URL scheme these days. Have you considered XHR? Or, better still, using a local http server?

Comment: @Jaromanda, thanks, that did the trick

Answer (score 11):

For chrome you still need `--allow-file-access-from-files` (and I recommend installing a [separate chrome](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) and using it solely for these projects to stay secure), but just shim `fetch()` for `XMLHttpRequest` for `file://` requests:

```js
if (/^file:\/\/\//.test(location.href)) {
    let path = './';
    let orig = fetch;
    window.fetch = (resource) => ((/^[^/:]*:/.test(resource)) ?
        orig(resource) :
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            let fail = (error) => {reject(error)};
            ['error', 'abort'].forEach((event) => { request.addEventListener(event, fail); });

            let pull = (expected) => (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (
                    request.responseType == expected ||
                    (expected == 'text' && !request.responseType)
                )
                    resolve(request.response);
                else
                    reject(request.responseType);
            }));

            request.addEventListener('load', () => (resolve({
                arrayBuffer : () => (pull('arraybuffer')),
                blob        : () => (pull('blob')),
                text        : () => (pull('text')),
                json        : () => (pull('json'))
            })));
            request.open('GET', resource.replace(/^\//, path));
            request.send();
        })
    );
}
```

This shim will;

- only activate for html files opened locally (outer `if` statement),
- call the normal `fetch()` for any url that doesn't specify protocol (and thus non-`file://` requests), and
- will replace absolute paths (`/root/bob.html`) with ones relative to the current path (since that would dangerously evaluate to `C:\` or equivalent)

Set `path` to something else if your `index.html` isn't actually at the root for the project.
If you need support for [init](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters), or anything other than `text()`, you'll need to add it.
Explicit `file://` requests wont be fulfilled, that's on purpose, but if you *really* do know what you're doing, you'll know how to make this work for you, and if you don't you shouldn't.

---

The following is useful if you're going to be doing this for multiple files. Swap out `'./'` for `document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-root')`. Now you can put that snippet into its own file, say `filesystemHelper.js`, and call like so in the various files:

```html
<script src="../filesystemHelper.js" data-root="../"></script>
```

Pretty snazzy.

Comment: Stick it in a `<script>` tag before your code runs using `fetch()`

Comment: Note that this shim has some limitations: it doesn't include `ok` and other `Response` members.  It also looks like Chrome on Windows doesn't guess the MIME type based on the file extension, at least not for `.json`

Comment: Isn't `XMLHttpRequest` also blocked locally in Chrome?  This error still occurs: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'x' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy`. Am I doing this wrong, or does this not work out of the box?

Comment: you bloody legend