# How to properly load local JSON in D3?

Tags: json, d3.js

Trying to load a local .json-file from the same folder in D3 (and logging it to the console), but there are two errors in the console:

> d3.v5.js:5908 Fetch API cannot load
>   [buildings.json - file]. URL scheme must be
>   "http" or "https" for CORS request. json @ d3.v5.js:5908 (anonymous) @
>   index.html:10
>
> d3.v5.js:5908 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to
>   fetch
>       at Object.json (d3.v5.js:5908)
>       at index.html:10 json @ d3.v5.js:5908 (anonymous) @ index.html:10 Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @ index.html:10

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
d3.json("buildings.json").then(data => console.log(data))
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody see the reason & have a solution?

Comment: don't use d3.json to fetch your data if that's your datasource

Answer (score 3):

`d3.json` uses `fetch`.

```
export default function(input, init) {
  return fetch(input, init).then(responseJson);
}
```

https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/src/json.js

So you are dealing with the same problem described in these SO posts.

- [Importing local json file using d3.json does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214293/importing-local-json-file-using-d3-json-does-not-work)
- ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)
- [Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/woshi/Desktop/P5/p5/JSON/birds.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445639/fetch-api-cannot-load-file-c-users-woshi-desktop-p5-p5-json-birds-json-url)

> You are facing a problem with cross origin resource sharing which is a security feature by your browser.
>
> Two options two avoid this:
>
> 1. use a webserver. To just run a simple webserver for your static html/js files something like the npm http-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) could be used
> 2. Change your chrome startup parameters and let it know that you want to ignore this security feature. You can do this by changing your startup configuration for example like this
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\development"
>
> The parameters --disable-web-security --user-data-dir are the important part here.
>
> **Note: Just use this for development. You allow cross origin requests by this for all websites you visit.**

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility mentioned in [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode) is to use a browser extension like [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)