# Next.js routing error in website tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For me the next.js tutorial https://github.com/zeit/next-learn-demo.git
has a problem at all stages past stage 2 "dynamic routing". Even though in the stages afterwards on stages 3 to 8 the dynamic routing should already be working.

What i assumed was the problems is that the file .next/routing appeared to be missing.

As such the tutorial asked implementation of code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

and

```
const router = useRouter();
```

does not do anything.

leading to the error on clicking the link:

[screenshot of next.js browser syntax error inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcN5p.png)

Why is the routing file not in the .next folder?

the react version is 16.10.2 (installed today through tutorial instructions)
the format of code is what is in the tutorial copy pasted. (no hook rule breaking)
there are no react duplicates.

Comment: `console.log(router)` see what that brings up

Comment: console.log(router)
VM38:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

does not seem to be available

Comment: instead of writing it console could you write this console line in your code, i.e. right after `const router = useRouter();`

Comment: THe console doesnt vie anything when i do this.

Further there is this in the console:

index.js:1 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/next-learn-demo/8-deploying/node_modules/next/dist/client/router.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Suggesting that it is not loading for that reason, along with 5 other api fetch requests

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445639/fetch-api-cannot-load-file-c-users-woshi-desktop-p5-p5-json-birds-json-url

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using useRouter() in class component. useRouter is a hook and used only in functional components.

in class components we use withRouter HOC. "router" object is accessible as

```
this.props.router
```