# How can I resolve the error "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request." for this code

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

It shows below message in the `console`.

> sandbox.js:1 Fetch API cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/Lizzi/Desktop/novice%20to%20ninja/todos/luigi.json.
>   URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

I'm new to `aynchronouse` programming but I have read up on `CORS` solutions and tried things like getting a chrome extension and disabling web security for my google chrome but it still doesn't work.

```
fetch('todos/luigi.json').then((response)=>{
  console.log('resolved',response);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('rejected', err);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with a full url in fetch?

Comment: *“disabling web secutity for my google chrome”* Don’t do that, it opens up a huge risk if you do anything else in the browser. Anyway: you can’t make Fetch/XHR requests to other local from a local file, so you’ll need to start up a local server somehow, maybe with [Python](https://www.python.org/) (`python -m http.server`) or [XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/), for example.

Comment: how? make sure the *url scheme*  is either `http` or `https` - the answer is in the error

Comment: As long as you are just playing a bit with fetch you can temporarily disable CORS.  Have a look at the dupe to see how. However always make sure to reenable it (restart the browser) after testing. On the long term, hosting a small testing server (either locally or remote) might be a good idea.

Comment: it works with a full url.

Comment: [You can do it without disabling security outright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59925724/2518317) (but you do need to enable `file://` requests)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to be serving your index.html locally or have your site hosted on a live server somewhere for the Fetch API to work properly. The files need to be served using the http or https protocols.

If you just clicked on your index.html from your file explorer than your browser is grabbing those files directly from your file system. This is why the error is showing you an absolute path from the root folder on you computer.

Try installing one of these...
- npm serve
- Live server (an extension for Visual Studio Code if you are using that)

Or whatever server that will work with your environment.

Should work fine once you spin up a server :) happy coding!

Comment: [You dont need to spin up a server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59925724/2518317) if you've enabled `file://` requests

Comment: @Hashbrown how to do that?

Comment: @Hashbrown how to enable the file:// request?

Comment: @YingStyle The Answer linked by Hashbrown explains it. Fetch doesn't support `file://` on Chrome, but he posted a workaround because XMLHttpRequest works (if you --allow-file-access-from-files). BTW: Firefox allows `file://` with fetch if you set `privacy.file_unique_origin=false` in `about:config`

Comment: I use liveserver in visual studio code. And it works! You need to install LiveServer extension and then right click your HTML file to run visit the page like localhost:5500