# UNO WASM app stuck on Splash Screen when opened after publishing to a local folder

Tags: c#, uno-platform

Created the UNO app. Designed a page in XAML and runs in Debug mode. Published to the local folder and opens up the index.html page. Gets stuck on the splash screen with errors in the browser console. Below is the attached screenshot.

[image: Stucks on Splash Screen with errors in console]

Answer (score 1):

The Uno Bootstrapper [is currently using `fetch`](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/blob/709170090b0a9d43732b80434f3895bd29e72ca4/src/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/WasmScripts/uno-bootstrap.js#L309) to get the wasm payload. And it seems you cannot use this method to load a file on drive.

Maybe there's a workaround (didn't try) by specifying `--allow-file-access-from-file` when starting your chromium-based browser (Chrome or Edge) as [mentionned on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59925724/1176099).

Another fix would be to change the Bootstrapper to use XHR for file access as [mentionned on this page](https://gitlab.pagedmedia.org/tools/pagedjs/issues/86): we accept PRs ;-).

Comment: The second link is dead :-(