# React Native Fetch(uri) says network [TypeError: Network request failed], When I try to retrieve local image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, blob, fetch

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkZckepfm2Q

is a tutorial on blob fetch for image uploads to Firebase storage.  I did this exactly like he did and mine doesn't work... Please help.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'


export let uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {  
    const resp = await fetch(uri);  //network [TypeError: Network request failed]
    console.log('resp:',resp)
    const blob = await resp.blob();    
    console.log('blob:',blob)
    let ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('eventapp/' + imageName)
    return ref.put(blob)
}
```

Comment: how does your `uri` look like?

Comment: "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FHere_We_Go-3c114bf3-e175-434a-9845-b541d3c6a453/Camera/eee042f2-54e8-41d5-ac15-0a21f7da65b4.jpg",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch request to local file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working)

Comment: you cannot load local files using `fetch`

Comment: What is this guy doing for that video to work?

Comment: improved syntax