# problem when try to fetch data from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I have some problems when I try to fetch the data, I didn't get response.
I write the path correctly? 
I attached the part of the code and pic of my project hierarchy.

```
let transportation = [];


const init = () => {
  fetch('/data/transportationDataCheck.json')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      transportation = data;
    }).then(() => {
      renderList(transportation);
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: Look in the console and/or network tab. What error do you get?

Comment: I think you need to check the path is correct or not . to ensure that check browser network .  just try with path ../data/transportationDataCheck.json

Comment: There are three problems with the code in the question, but neither of them is likely to be the root problem (though one of them might have pointed you to the root problem): 1. You're not checking for HTTP errors. This is a footgun in the `fetch` API (I write about it [here]()). Check `response.ok` in your first fulfillment handler to see if the HTTP request worked (sadly, `fetch` only rejects on *network* errors, not HTTP errors). 2. There's no reason to have the last two fulfillment handlers, just use one. 3. You're not handling rejection. FWIW: https://pastebin.com/hPDUU25i

Comment: what do you get if you try the path in the URL directly `APP_URL/data/transportationDataCheck.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
const data = require("../data/transportationDataCheck.json")
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Or you may try after changing little URL

```
let transportation = [];


const init = () => {
  fetch('../data/transportationDataCheck.json')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      transportation = data;
    }).then(() => {
      renderList(transportation);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serve a static file with a fetch command, which inherently requires the file to be served by a server.

Someone had a similar issue here: [Fetch request to local file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working)

Depending on what type of file this is, you may not need to make a fetch. You could probably instead require the file:

````
var transportationDataCheck = require('./data/transportationDataCheck.json');```
````

Answer (score -1):

Use ./ at the beginning of the path

```html
fetch('./data/transportationDataCheck.json')
.then(response => {
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  // Work with JSON data here
  console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => {
  // Do something for an error here
})
```