# Local JSON File not being recognized in React with fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am having some trouble with my local JSON file not being recognized in React with `fetch()`

Code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Datatable from "./datatable";
import Data from './data/data.json';
import './App.css';

require("es6-promise").polyfill();
require("isomorphic-fetch");

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");
  const [searchColumns, setSearchColumns] = useState(["first_name", "last_name"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(Data)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setData(json));
  }, []);
```

... some add'l code continues which I can add if helpful.

[image: File map if helpful]

I'm literally just getting a blank page. I also tried fetching the actual path to the JSON file out of curiosity, but I received a webpack loader error.

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, but you may not need fetch at all (fetch is for getting files from a web server, not local files). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your data locally, you don't need to fetch it on remote server. Try is instead :

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");
  const [searchColumns, setSearchColumns] = useState(["first_name", "last_name"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // use your data here
    setData(Data);
    console.log('data', Data);
  });

  return(
    <div>yeah it works !</div>
  )
}
```

Here is an working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-can3gq?file=data.json