# Can't fetch files from my local directory with fetch() API in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, fetch

I cant fetch files from my local directory ::

```
  async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch("dina.png");
    const data = await response.blob();
    document.querySelector("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  }
  getData();
```

ERRORS

ERROR : cannot load - file path - . URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request. getData @ file.html:12 (anonymous) @ file.html:16.
ERROR : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at getData (file.html:12)enter code here
at file.html:16

Comment: use a http server, plenty of simple ones around - though apparently chrome has a command line switch to enable such a thing, but ...

Comment: You cannot access your local file system like this, browser prevents this for security reasons. Use http server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch request to local file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working)

Comment: Please try to make sure that your question has not already been answered already. It really shows a lack of research on your part.