# Handle url and file input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two `input`s: `type="file"` and `type="url"`. Thus the user has the possibility to provide either a local file or a remote file.
In any case, after reading the file, the text should be processed by the same function `func`.

I already used `fetch`. However, `fetch` cannot handle local files (e.g. [Fetch request to local file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working)). Thus a combination with `FileReader` is the next idea. But `FileReader` is not `async`; a work around was suggested [here](https://simon-schraeder.de/posts/filereader-async/).

But are there better way to handle this common situation?

Comment: What are you intending on doing with the files? You have to get a server involved though to avoid CORS - a server can download any public url pretty easily, but be mindful of the attack vectors that open up when somebody can ask a server to download any given URL.

Comment: I'm interested in plotting remote or local data files. Some files can be still retrieved, e.g. `fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/spectral.csv').then(d => d.text()).then(console.log)`.

Comment: if fetch could get local files from an online origin.. then any webpage could literally look into your files.. I mean that's not exactly *private*

Comment: " But FileReader is not async" — Yes, it is. It doesn't return a promise, but it is asynchronous. (It can't just return a promise as it supports things like incremental reading which aren't a straight forward "success/fail" with nothing else.

Comment: It is a pity that this question was closed. The "duplicate" link does not help me. It uses neither fetch nor FileReader. I understand that callback is needed in both cases.  Also my question is not about CORS. Even if the url is on the same domain, the problem remains.

Comment: I realised in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804354/11769765 that `FileReader` has the `.text()` method, too, as `fetch`! Thus no extra `Promise` wrapper is needed. Just `async function readfile(path) {file = (path instanceof File)? path : (await fetch(path)); return await file.text()}` will do the job and handle both cases: `readfile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/spectral.csv').then(console.log)`. Similar a local file could be passed as file object from `input type=file`. A much easier solution than the suggested "duplicate".

Comment: If you came up with a working solution, you can self-answer so that others can benefit too. And you'll get rep from any upvotes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804354/11769765 that `FileReader` has the `.text()` method, too, as `fetch`! Thus no extra `Promise` wrapper is needed. Just

```
async function readfile(path) {
    file = (path instanceof File)? path : (await fetch(path));
    return await file.text()
}
```

will do the job and handle both cases: `readfile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/spectral.csv').then(console.log)`. Similar a local file could be passed as file object from `input type=file`. A much easier solution than the suggested "duplicate".

```js
async function readfile(path) {
    file = (path instanceof File)? path : (await fetch(path));
    return await file.text()
}
```

```html
<input type=url onchange="(async ()=>{result.innerHTML = await readfile(this.value)})()" value="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/spectral.csv"><br>
<input type=file onchange="(async ()=>{result.innerHTML = await readfile(this.files[0])})()">

<div id="result"></div>
```